# Using Matlab to randomly split an Excel Sheet

Tags: matlab

I have an Excel sheet containing 1838 records and I need to RANDOMLY split these records into 3 Excel Sheets. I am trying to use Matlab but I am quite new to it and I have just managed the following code:

```
[xlsn, xlst, raw] = xlsread('data.xls');

numrows = 1838; 

randindex = ceil(3*rand(numrows, 1));

raw1 = raw(:,randindex==1);
raw2 = raw(:,randindex==2);
raw3 = raw(:,randindex==3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general procedure will be to read the spreadsheet into some matlab variables, operate on those matrices such that you end up with three thirds and then write each third back out.

So you've got the read covered with `xlsread`, that results in the two matrices `xlsnum` and `xlstxt`. I would suggest using the syntax

```
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread('data.xls');
```

In the `xlsread` help file (you can access this by typing `doc xlsread` into the command window) it says that the three output arguments hold the numeric cells, the text cells and the whole lot. This is because a matlab matrix can only hold one type of value and a spreadsheet will usually be expected to have text or numbers. The `raw` value will hold all of the values but in a 'cell array' instead, a different kind of matlab data type.

So then you will have a cell array valled `raw`. From here you want to do three things:

1. work out how many rows you have (I assume each record is a row) by using the `size` function and specifying the appropriate dimension (again check the help file to see how to do this)
2. create an index of random numbers between 1 and 3 inclusive, which you can use as a mask

   `randindex = ceil(3*rand(numrows, 1));`
3. apply the mask to your cell array to extract the records matching each index

   `raw1 = raw(:,randindex==1); % do the same for the other two index values`
4. write each cell back to a file

   `xlswrite('output1.xls', raw1);`

You will probably have to fettle the arguments to get it to work the way you want but be sure to check the `doc functionname` page to get the syntax just right. Your main concern will be to get the indexing correct - matlab indexes row-first whereas spreadsheets tend to be column-first (e.g. cell A2 is column A and row 2, but matlab matrix element M(1,2) is the first row and the second column of matrix M, i.e. cell B1).

UPDATE: to split the file evenly is surprisingly more trouble: because we're using random numbers for the index it's not guaranteed to split evenly. So instead we can generate a vector of random floats and then pick out the lowest 33% of them to make index 1, the highest 33 to make index 3 and let the rest be 2.

```
randvec = rand(numrows, 1); % float between 0 and 1
pct33 = prctile(randvec,100/3); % value of 33rd percentile
pct67 = prctile(randvec,200/3); % value of 67th percentile
randindex = ones(numrows,1);
randindex(randvec>pct33) = 2;
randindex(randvec>pct67) = 3;
```

It probably still won't be absolutely even - 1838 isn't a multiple of 3. You can see how many members each group has this way

```
numel(find(randindex==1))
```

Comment: Without your actual xls sheet it's hard to tell what's wrong - it works for me when I generate a test matrix using `magic` but that's not saying much. Check the size of your `raw` array using `size(raw)`. I would use that to define `numrows` rather than hardcoding it, it's more robust to things like this.

Comment: The raw array contains all the dataset perfectly and it is 1839*20

Comment: what is raw1 = raw(:,randindex==1) doing please? and do I have to include any loop?

Comment: The main thing to solve your problem is probably that the indexes should be swapped. Try `raw(randindex==1,:)` instead.

Comment: It will probably be useful to spend a bit of time reading about how matlab indexes values (http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). You're using cell arrays so there are a few differences but the principles are the same.

Comment: The `raw(:,randindex==1)` line is selecting elements from the cell array. The ':' operator means 'all of them', the `randindex==1` entry is performing a test on the randindex vector which returns a 'logical' array of 1 or 0. It applies this logical array as a mask to the columns of raw, selecting the ones with a 1. The effect is to pick out columns of the array for which the random index matches the value '1'. There are a lot of concepts combined here, I would recommend reading up on matlab indexing, it'll make matlab a lot more comprehensible.

Comment: It worked thanks! One last thing, it does not split the data into 3 equal parts, can this be done?

Comment: I've added a bit to the answer, hope it helps : )